# How to slowly fill text on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I currently have text on a canvas that is white. I would like to be able to slowly and smoothly fill the text with another color (red) from left to right. Is there a way to do this so at times a letter will be white on a fraction and red on the other side?

An example using the word "Color".

The "Col" are red. The next "o" has 25% red (left) and 75% white (right). The "r" is full white.

**Update**

Thanks for all the help. I noticed it works even better if you add ctx.beginPath() before the clip object.

I have added a little bit to the idea and created a small js object that seems to work nicely for my current project. It may not be the most elegant js but hopefully it helps out someone else that wants to do this later. There is a slight issue I noticed with the size of text changing when it starts to fill, not sure why. http://jsfiddle.net/WRAFA/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this whit the composite operation source-in. If you first draw your text with your background color (white) with composite operation source-over and then draws a colored-rect over it with soruce-in its only intersection between the text and rect that will be drawn. I made a small example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBSr2/8/)

Comment: This is almost what I need! The only thing is I cant seem to see the text if I change the background to black and keep the text white. Is there a way to make the text show up and then have it fill?

Comment: I did a little bit of tweaking and I think I have achieved success. Here is an edited link to what you put. (I don't have edit privileges here yet.) [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MBSr2/20/).

Answer (score 2):

Nice job on fixing Richard's fiddle.  I've made a couple improvements.

1. you asked for a black canvas background with white text.
2. The use of `setInterval` is not recommended here.  You are running draw for ever and ever and ever and ever and ever and....  I have fixed the fiddle to use `setTimeout` so that it stops the draw events as soon as you get to the edge of the canvas.

The adjusted fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/d4Jef/1/

One thing I would recommend, though.  Instead of using compositing, you should write text using a *clipping region*.  The problem with `source-in` compositing is that if your text were written over some kind of image with opaque pixels, then filling a rect over this would blow away your background.  You got away with it here because you had nothing else on your canvas *except* the text.  So it's better to go with a clipping region.

Here is the version with the clipping approach: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZgNz/2/

Note the use of the additional green square to highlight which this approach works in general.

Comment: I used setInterval just to keep the code short, you use of setTimeout is ofcourse much better. I just wanted to show my idea. 
Using a clipping region instead of different composite operations is probably much better, all composite operations (except the default source-over) quite slow

Comment: I'm sure you did. :-) I was just giving the OP some additional guidance as a good deed.